# How to make argparse work in executable program

Tags: python, argparse, pyinstaller

I have a command line script which uses the argparse module.

```
import argparse 

def run():
    print 'Running'

def export():
    print 'Exporting'

def argument_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('run', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('export', action='store_true')
    return parser.parse_args()

args = argument_parser()
if args.run:
    run()
else:
    export()
```

Now it works just fine when run from command line `> python myfile.py run` etc.

However using `pyinstaller` I've made an executable from it and if I open the main.exe file I got `too few arguments` error which is quite logical. But I want to be able to open (double click) main.exe (which open the comman line tool) and have the command line wait for my command (run or export in this case). Instead it just throws the error and quits.

Comment: Hi rojas, I don't understand well what you want to achieve

Comment: When I open the executable it throws the error too few arguments I did not even have a change to type in anything!

Comment: Can you define "listen"?

Comment: What do you mean by "open the main.exe file"? Run it?

Comment: I've edited the post and explained.

Comment: Try running the exe from a command line and pass your arguments there. If you want your program to wait for an input, I don't think that `argparse` is suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`cmd` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) to create a shell.

You can then use `cmd.Cmd()` class you create to run single commands through the [`cmd.Cmd().onecmd()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.onecmd); pass in the `sys.argv` command line, joined with spaces:

```
from cmd import Cmd
import sys

class YourCmdSubclass(Cmd):
    def do_run(*args):
        """Help text for run"""
        print('Running')

    def do_export(*args):
        """Help text for export"""
        print('Exporting')

    def do_exit(*args):
        return -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = YourCmdSubclass()
    command = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    if command:
        sys.exit(c.onecmd(command))
    c.cmdloop()
```

Help is automatically provided by the `help` command.

Comment: And where do I fit `argument_parser()` into this code?

Comment: @rojas: drop `argument_parser` altogether. The `Cmd` class replaces it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  So your solution is to abandon argparse?  I don't see how Cmd replaces it; you'd have to rewrite the whole thing.  (Unless I am missing something).

Comment: @Jiminion no, I’m telling the OP to use cmd because it is the tool they actually wanted. From the question: *But I want to be able to open (double click) main.exe (which open the comman line tool) and have the command line wait for my command*. They wanted a shell-like prompt, and that’s what cmd provides.

Answer (score 1):

## You can fill `sys.argv` manually, for example:

```py
# Created By BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2023-12-23 09:41:29+0800
import argparse
import sys

try:
    argparse.ArgumentParser()
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception:", e)
else:
    print("No exception, it worked!")

if len(sys.argv) == 0:
    sys.argv.append(sys.executable)

try:
    argparse.ArgumentParser()
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception:", e)
else:
    print("No exception, it worked!")
```

**The output:**

```
Exception: list index out of range
No exception, it worked!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `./` to run the command and use the usual `argparse` inputs like so:

```
$ ./myfile -arg -arg
```